# Check status of message queue connection in Apache Camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka, akka-camel

I am using Apache Camel in Akka and am trying to check at given intervals what the status of the message queue is.
I see the queue logs its status periodically, but I would like to programmatically be able to make this check.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of status or heart beat check should be part of QoS module. Camel is not intended for that. However if your architecture design permits, you can write a camel route as a part of your QoS module to do that. (i.e you can put a test message to a queue and consume using camel components. But you have keen on the logic for few scenarios like "to do a status check QoS putting a test message to a queue which is being listened by the business logic").